# serializing an array and storing in DB

Tags: php, mysql

i have an array like

```
$newArray = $_POST[$newId];
print_r($newArray);
```

it prints like

```
Array ( [1] => Yes [2] => a [3] => b [4] => c [5] => d [6] => e [7] => f [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => )
```

but when i try to store in in db after serializing like

```
serialize($newArray)
```

it get stored like

```
s:211:"Array
(
    [1] => Yes
    [2] => ab
    [3] => c
    [4] => d
    [5] => e
    [6] => f
    [7] =>
    [8] =>
    [9] =>
    [10] =>
    [11] =>
    [12] =>
    [13] =>
    [14] =>
)

";
```

which is a single array element in DB..how do i properly serialize the element.

Comment: You ask "how do i properly serialize the element", but the question is to you: what do you consider "proper serialization" of an array in the DB?  You haven't shared your data model or expectations, so it's rather hard to answer your question.

Comment: I assume proper serialization should be `a:14:{i:1;s:3:"Yes";i:2;s:2:"ab";...}`

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly posting the array?  What does `is_array($_POST[$newId])` return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's serializing a string, not an array.  Are you sure `$newArray` is an array?

The string returned from serialize starts with 's:211'.  This means that a string was passed into `serialize()`.  If an array were passed into `serialize()` the returned string would start with 'a:14'.

Comment: i was storing an array in a text field ....so i thing it got converted to string... how do i over come it..?

Comment: No, I meant that you are passing a string to `serialize()`, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

@pradeep 
where you storing $newArray in textfield, store it by serialling

```
$arrayString = $_POST['newId'];
```

You will get seriallized array in $arrayString.
If you want to use that array before storing in database , use unserialize , else directly store in database as that is already seriallized.

```
$array = unserialize($arrayString);
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: This isn't the best idea.  What if one of the strings had a comma in it?

Comment: I don't think it works this way.  I like the old answer better (you just can't have a string with a comma).

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I understand the question, if you don't want to serialize though, and if you want to pass it from a text field, maybe do custom syntax like - 1:a;b:2;c:3

then explode(';',$string); loop that and for the result, explode(':',$rows)

make the delimiters more difficult to clash

```
explode("[[;]]", string); // 1]]:[[b[[;]]
```